# Are there see-through colors in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I want to partially tint picture boxes in a windows form app, is there any way to do it?
By 'partially tint', I mean a see-through color.
I'm using VS Windows Forms C++

Comment: There is no such thing as a "see-through color". What you can do is create an overlay window with a solid color, and then set the overlay's alpha translucency. Otherwise, modify the pixel values of the image to apply tinting to it before placing it into the PictureBox.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In an RGBA color model, there certainly are "see-through" color values.

Comment: @BenVoigt sure, but most UI systems don't support the A(lpha) component

Comment: You can build a Custom Control derived from PictureBox (or Control), in its Constructor set `this->SetStyle(ControlStyles::ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles::Opaque, true); this->SetStyle(ControlStyles::OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);`. Override `CreateParams` and add `auto cp = __super::CreateParams; cp->ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT; return cp;`. Now you can override `OnPaint` and fill the ClientRectangle with a semi-transparent Color. You can drag the Custom Control over any other Control in your Form, you'll *see-through* anything under it (some smart *refreshing* required).

Comment: BTW, if you need an example, let me know.

Comment: An example would help a lot.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.